# Regex expression to check if contains more than 2 repeated characters

Tags: regex, angular, angular8, angular9

I am checking in my validation form if there are repeated more than two times the same character.

I have tried this expression ([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{2,} but it doesn't work properly because if I add aaA it founds the string and it shouldn't because "aaA" is permitted. Also it doesn't check if it is repeated a special character.

Here is how I applied my code:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        newpassword: new FormControl(
          '',
          Validators.compose([
            Validators.required,
            CustomValidators.patternValidator(/[(\[a-zA-Z0-9\])\\1{2,}]/, {
              hasRepeatedCharacters: true,
            }),
          ])
        ),
      },
      { validators: this.password }
    );
```

Any idea?

Comment: `([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{2,}` wont match `aaA` unless you use `i`-ignorecase flag. Also the regex inside of a code piece is really odd because of excess braces and escape slashes

Comment: Are you looking for repeated characters anywhere in the string or consecutively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are considering to be invalid, you want this:

```
/(.)\1{2,}/
```

Comment: That is working fine in javascript but do you know how is in typescript? I have tested in my code but is not working

Comment: As as far as I know regex is the same in Typescript, are you getting some sort of error?

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It worked. My problem was that I was adding /[ ]/ at the start and the end of the expression for this reason didn't work. So the final solution is CustomValidators.patternValidator(/(.)\1{2,}/, {
              hasRepeatedCharacters: true,
            }),

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex to detect any character repeated 2 or more times:

```
(.)\1{2,}
```

In order to capture `aaA` (repeated letters irrespective of their case) as well, you'll need to add the case-insensitive `i` flag.

Comment: That is working fine in javascript but do you know how is in typescript? I have tested in my code but is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/(.)(?=\1.*\1)/`, assuming you allow the repeated characters to be non-consecutive:

```js
const pat = /(.)(?=.*\1.*\1)/;
[
  "a",
  "aa",
  "aaa",
  "zba1a1za",
  "aaA",
  "aaAA",
  "aAaAa",
  "aAbbAb",
].forEach(e => console.log(`'${e}' => ${pat.test(e)}`));
```